# How much work is done in pumping water out over the top edge in order to empty (a) half the tank (b) all of the tank.

Tags: calculus

Rectangular tank is base of 4 feet by 5 feet and a height of 4 feet that is full of water. The water weighs 62.4 pounds per cubic foot.

This is what I got.
$$Volume = (5*4*4) $$

$${\Delta}F = 62.4 * 80 $$

$${\Delta}W = 4992(4-y)$$

$$\int_{0}^{4} 4992(4-y) dy = 0 $$
$$\int_{2}^{4} 4992(4-y) dy = -9984 $$

Comment: My book doesn't go over this problem at all. It showed an example of emptying a spherical tank. It didn't explain how to solve other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just change your $\Delta F$.

$$\Delta F = 62.4 \cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot \Delta y$$

$$\Delta W = 62.4 \cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot (4-y) \Delta y $$

Then you can set up your definite integral accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! The answer is correct but I am still confused. What did I do wrong or how did you come up with your answer?

Comment: Your $\Delta F$ is the force on the whole tank. When you replace the whole height $4$ by $\Delta y$, it becomes the force on the slice of the volume. The idea of integral is to add up the work done on each slice of volume.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  My book talked about none of this. Thanks so much :)