# Tank pump problem

Tags: calculus

I've been working on this problem for the last hour and can't quite seem to get it right.

A tank is full of water. Find the work required to pump the water out of the spout. Use the fact that water weighs 62.5 lb/ft3. (Assume a = 4 ft, b = 5 ft, and c = 6 ft.)

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDh20.gif)

I've figured out that the volume is 4*5*6/2= 60 and the mass= 60*62.5 = 3750
I then integrated 3750x from 0 to 4.
1875x^2]=30,000

Have I done this problem correctly?

Comment: No idea - what steps did you take to *get* that answer?

Comment: Your are right that the mass is $60 ft^3\cdot 62.5 lb/ft^3=3750 lb$. But what is your question ?

Comment: How much work would it take to pump the water out of the spout?

Comment: Just a guess, did you use integration to find the total work done by considering the infinitesimal work done by pumping a slice at a distance h from the top?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185952/how-much-work-is-done-in-pumping-water-out-over-the-top-edge-in-order-to-empty?rq=1

Comment: What you've integrated doesn't make sense.   You have to consider the tank being sliced into infinitely small slices along the horizontal.  To pump the water out, you have to move each slice from its original position to the top of the tank, so that requires work which would be the weight of the slice multiplied by the slices distance to the top.  You then have to sum or integrate all the contributions from each slice to get the total work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is not taking advantage of units. The volume $V=\frac12(4 ft)(5 ft)(6 ft)=60 ft^3$, Then the weight is $w=\gamma V=(62.5\,lb/ft^3)(60 ft^3)=3750\,lb$. Since work is force$\times$distance, you need a distance here, and the appropriate one is the distance you must raise the center of mass to get the $H_2O$ out of the spout. Since the center of mass of a uniform triangular area is $\frac13$ of the way from any side, the distance is $(4 ft)/3$ so the work is $(3750\,lb)(4 ft)/3=5000ft\cdot lb$. In calculus, the area of a horizontal section $y\,ft$ from the lowest point is $(5ft)\times(6ft)\times y/(4ft)=7.5\,y\, ft^2$. You have to lift that slice $4ft-y$, so work is
$$w=\int_0^4(62.5)(4-y)(7.5y)dy=(62.5)\left[15y^2-2.5y^3\right]_0^4=5000ft\cdot lb$$